# Worldwide uggc/uggcf protocol usage and support?

Tags: https, rot13

I have been starting to see uggc/uggcf (rot-13 encoded http/https) links show up in our system.

1. Are these worth supporting, is there actually a demand for it? The IETF document ([link](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-farah-uggc-protocol-01)) has not been touched since 2001 and I cannot find much information on them at all.
2. Is there an area of the world where this is more common? I've only noticed them since we went world-wide.
3. The document describes it as a method to 'secure' the url as well as the data. What is the value of rot-13 encoding the data if it can be reversed without a key? HTTPS handles all of this, except for the domain itself.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old answer but this is an interesting topic so I'll try to answer your question:

The "Encrypted Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- UGGC/1.0" specification, is an April Fools RFC. The IETF releases these almost yearly on 1st April, and ROT13 "encryption" would be pointless, since by knowning the encryption algortihm, you would be able to "decrypt" the message, in this case the URL.

So no, it's not worth supporting, and it does not provide any "serious" protection. The only usage I've seen is in some CTFs or hacking/crypto challenges.